# Fragment pattern appears in render from a distance

Tags: rendering

I found that when rendering my Earth model from a distance, these patterns appear. I've checked and adjusted the clipping distances multiple times to see if it was a form of Z Fighting but it was not, and I've also removed doubles from all objects in the scene, each had 0 doubles. I'm not quite sure what's making this happen. Any suggestions I could try?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your render look like if you turn off the textures and use a solid color? Are the artifacts still there?

Comment: No, solid colour doesn't seem to feature the artifacts.